# Confusion regarding Cartan subalgebra of a Linear Lie algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

I am reading the book Introduction to Lie Algebra by Erdmann and Wildon, Chapter 12 Pg-126. I have the following problem:

Let $L$ be a classical lie Algebra. $H$ be the set of diagonal matrices in $L$. clearly $H$ is a commuting subalgebra of $L$, of semisimple elements. Now Let $L^{'}=L\cap Span\{\ e_{ij} | i\neq j \}\ $ be the subspace of off-diagonal matrices in $L$. We have that $L{'}$ is invariant under $ad h$ for every $h\in H$, hence the action of $ad H$ on this subspace is diagonalisable, so,

$$L^{'}=\bigoplus_{\alpha \in \phi} L_{\alpha}$$, where for $\alpha \in H^{*}$, $L_{\alpha}$ is the $\alpha-$ eigenspace of $H$, on the off-diagonal part of $L$, and $\phi=\{\ \alpha \in H^{*} | \alpha \neq 0, L_{\alpha} \neq 0 \}\ $.

Then the book asserts that hence $$L=L_{0} \oplus \bigoplus_{\alpha \in \phi} L_{\alpha} \hspace{3 cm}...... (1)$$

where $L_{0}=\{\ l\in L| [h, l]=0 \forall h\in H  \}\ $. In other words, $L_{0}=C_{L}(H)$.

Then the book asserts that $H=L_{0}$, which will mean that $H$ is a Cartan subalgebra for $L$. To prove their assertion they prove the following lemma:

Let $L\subset gl(n,\mathbb{C})$ and $H$ be as above described. Suppose that for all non-zero $h\in H$, there exists some $\alpha \in \phi$ such that $\alpha(h)\neq 0$. Then $H=L_{0}$, and hence $H$ is a Cartan subalgebra of $L$.

Now my question are as follows:

(a) why does the direct sum in (1) hold?

(b) I understand the proof of the Lemma but the Lemma carries with itself an extra condition, that "Suppose that for all non-zero $h\in H$, there exists some $\alpha \in \phi$ such that $\alpha(h)\neq 0$." I don't see why this condition is satisfied in the afore mentioned case so that the lemma implies that $H=L_{0}$.

Comment: I think (1) holds due to a result in linear algebra about vector spaces decomposing as a direct sum of eigenspaces

Comment: My question is why $L_{0}\cap L^{'} = \{ 0 \}\ $.

Comment: The intersection is trivial because one is the eigenspace for the eigenvalue $0$ and the other is a direct sum of eigenspaces for non-zero eigenvalues (and no vector can have multiple eigenvalues).

Comment: But why can"t the off- diagonal part have. a common zero eigen space?

Comment: What is meant by "a classical Lie algebra" here? Is it a semisimple one over $\mathbb{C}$ embedded in some $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: Of $A_{l}, B_{l}, C_{l}, D_{l}$ type

Comment: Well, but the Lie algebra $L := \lbrace \begin{pmatrix} 0 & a & c \\ -a & 0& b \\ -c & -b & 0 \end{pmatrix} : a,b,c \in \mathbb{C} \rbrace$ is of type $A_1$ (isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$). Don't we have $H = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ and $L_0 = L$ here? My point is that if you (or the book) speak of "diagonal matrices", you (or the book) seem to have a specific representation as matrices (=embedding into $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$) in mind.